# can't change path of script file in vb scripting in asp page

Tags: jquery, vbscript

i have a html page and database vb script is connected to it, when i click search button the script will redirect the main url of the page.

```
<%
   If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
   Course=Request.Form("Courses")
   location=Request.Form("location")
   Course=lcase(replace(Course, " ", "-"))
   location=lcase(replace(location, " ", "-"))
   Response.Redirect "http://www.example.com/+location+"/"+Course+"-institute.html"


end if

%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script id="url" type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
     <select  name="Courses" id="Course"  class="course sele-txt"></select>
     <select name="location" id="location" class="location sele-txt"></select>
     <input type="submit" id="search-btn" class="search-btn"  value="Search" name="btnSubmit" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i wanted to change the path of respond.js to src="http://www.example.com/js/repond.js" during the redirection process. i tried all the way. but i could not get it. can any one give me a solution

Comment: If you're just trying to reference a js file in a folder, regardless of your current location then you need to make it an absolute path instead.  Just change it to `src="/js/respond.js"` - that will also point to a subfolder off the site root.  Removing the first `/` makes it relative to the file it's included in.

Comment: thanks for ur comment, but the point is it is already in sub folder only. i want to change the path to 'src="http://www.example.com/js/repond.js"'

Comment: So you want to change the domain of the script include, but not change the page you're on?

Comment: yes i want to change the path of the script, but not the page

Comment: Okay, you do know that `Response.Redirect()` means you're going to load a completely different page anyway, yes?  So you put the correct path in the page that you're loading as the one you're currently on will be gone.

Comment: but the main page is main folder and the path response.Redirect() is creating subfolder in it Response.Redirect "http://www.example.com/+location+"/"+Course+"-institute.html"

Comment: actually the file path is www.example.com/js/respond.js. but it is show www.example/location/js/respond.js.

Comment: Pls give me a way to correct the path alone

Comment: Try my very first suggestion.  Change the js path so that it starts with `/`.  That means that no matter where the file that includes it is located, it will *always* look for the js file in `www.example.com/js/`